# SQLAlchemy querying with joins

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

With this models:

```
class Ball(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'balls'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    field_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fields.id'))
    field = relationship("Field", back_populates="fields")


class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fields'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String)
    fields= relationship("Ball", order_by=Ball.id, back_populates="field")
```

I'm trying to write query to access Field.nickname and Ball.field_id. With use of

```
result = session.query(Field, Ball).all()
print(result)
```

I'm able to retrieve

```
(<Field(id=1, nickname=stadium>, <Ball(id=1, field_id=newest)>), (<Field(id=1, nickname=stadium>, <Ball(id=2, field_id=oldest)>
```

but when using

```
result = session.query(Field).join(Ball).all()
print(result)
```

I'm getting empty list `[]`, doesn't matter if I'm applying any filters or not. According to [official docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins), `join` would come in handy if dealing with two tables, so this way I would be able to filter for the same id in both and I guess it would came in handy when displaying query results in jinja template.

Comment: That's an empty list, not a dictionary. It'd seem you have no Balls, so to speak - in other words the inner join produces no rows, since there are no `balls` with a mathing *field_id*.

Comment: Look at my question, you'll see that using another query, I'm able to retrieve both fields and balls - this query prints output without any filter applied.

Comment: Your first query performs a cross join, not an inner join. Different query, different results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in  your `Field` class - `back_populates='fields'` doesn't match up with the attribute name in `Ball`.

Try changing it to `back_populates='field'` so that it matches the attribute defined in `Ball`. With the relationship defined correctly sqlalchemy should be able to do the join automatically.

Comment: Right, I must have missed it, but now even when I fixed it, query still returns ``[]``.